# Proof that p prime divides binominal coefficient with p k

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be prime and $k\in\mathbb N, \ 0 < k < p.$

Claim: $p | \begin{pmatrix}p \\ k \end{pmatrix}$

Proof:

We know that $\begin{pmatrix}p \\ k \end{pmatrix} = \frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}=\frac{p(p-1)!}{k!(p-k)!}$

It's clear, that $\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}=\frac{p(p-1)!}{k!(p-k)!}$ is dividable by p. Thus $p | \frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}=\frac{p(p-1)!}{k!(p-k)!}$ and thus $ p | \begin{pmatrix}p \\ k \end{pmatrix}$

q.e.d.

Does this work?

Comment: you probably mean that $\begin{pmatrix}p \\ k\end{pmatrix}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$. And yes it does work

Comment: Any time you're trying to write a proof, if you find yourself writing "It's clear", it's probably not good enough. Also, in this case that's basically the only step in the proof so it's definitely not enough. You should use the definition of divisibility somewhere, for a start.

Comment: Actually you need to justify that $\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-k)!}$ is an integer before you can claim this to be a valid proof.

Comment: This doesn't work since it's not a all clear that $\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-k)!}$ is an integer. In particular, you're not using the hypothesis that $p$ is prime. If $p$ is not a prime, then this fails: $\frac{1}{4}{4 \choose 2} = \frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument shows that
$$\binom{p}{k} =p\left(\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(p-k)!}\right)$$
but it's not immediate that the factor ${\displaystyle{\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}}}$ is an integer.

To finish it, cross-multiply, and then use the primeness of $p$ . . .
\begin{align*}
\text{Thus,}\;\;&\binom{p}{k} =p\left(\frac{(p-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&p(p-1)!=(k!)\bigl((p-k)!\bigr)\binom{p}{k}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Since $p$ is prime,

- $0 < k < p\implies p\not\mid k!$$\\[4pt]$

  [since $p$ does not divide any of the factors $1,..,k$]$\\[4pt]$

  $0 < k < p\implies 0 < p - k < p \implies p\not\mid (p-k)!$$\\[4pt]$

  [since $p$ does not divide any of the factors $1,..,p-k$]$\\[4pt]$

In the equation
$$p(p-1)!=(k!)((p-k)!)\binom{p}{k}$$
it's clear that $p$ divides the LHS, hence $p$ divides the RHS.

Thus, $p$ divides the product of the $3$ integers 
$$k!,\;\;\;(p-k)!,\;\;\;\binom{p}{k}$$
hence, since $p$ is prime, $p$ must divide at least one of the $3$ factors.

Since $p\not\mid k!$, and $p\not\mid (p-k)!$, it follows that $p\,{\mid}\,{\large{\binom{p}{k}}}$, as was to be shown.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
k!\binom{p}{k}=p(p-1)\cdots (p-k+1)
$$
Suppose that towards a contradiction, $p$ does not divide $\binom{p}{k}$. Then because $p$ divides the LHS and $p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\quad \text{or}\quad p\mid b$, it follows that $p\mid k!$ so $p\mid j$ for some $1\leq j \leq k<p$, a contradiction.